# CGSize Coding/Decoding

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, codable, decodable

I want to encode and decode CGSize data type in Swift and store it in a Dictionary, but am not able to find any sample code how to do it. I tried this but it gives error:

```
 let size = CGSize(width: Int(100), height: Int(50))
 dictionary["size"] = try! size.encode(to: Encoder())

Error: 'Encoder' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
```

I understand Encoder is a protocol, which Encoder/Decoder class are we supposed to use?

Comment: Is there a reason to encode `size` before storing it into `dictionary`? If `dictionary` type is `[String: CGSize]`, you could directly `dictionary["size"] = size`.

Comment: Well, does CGSize confirm to Codable/plist? Because I also need to store this dictionary as plist & optionally send it to server.

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned, you cannot directly use `Encoder` since it is a protocol. Also, you are doing it improperly, size itself (`CGSize`) does *not* has `encode` method, the responsible one to encode is the encoder.

Assuming that `dictionary` type is `[String: Data]`, this is how you could do it:

```
var dictionary: [String: Data] = [: ]
let size = CGSize(width: Int(100), height: Int(50))

let sizeData = try JSONEncoder().encode(size)
dictionary["size"] = sizeData
```

For retrieving it:

```
let storedData = dictionary["size"]
let storedSize = try JSONDecoder().decode(CGSize.self, from: storedData!)
print(storedSize)
```

As you can see, we can use `JSONEncoder` and `JSONDecoder` to achieve it. Keep in mind that we are able to do it because `CGSize` is `Codable`.

---

Furthermore, you could check [Using Codables for Persisting Custom Objects in UserDefaults](https://medium.com/@ahmadfayyas/using-codables-for-persisting-custom-objects-in-userdefaults-aeb3625fbf36); Although It might be not directly related to your issue, I described how to deal with any similar case which could make it more clear to you.

Comment: Are CGSize & CGRect now Codable in Swift, that they can be saved in plist files or Dictionaries and can be transferred to server?

Comment: @DeepakSharma you could check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgsize Relationship section - "conforms to" and you'll notice that it conforms for both `Encodable` and `Decodable` (`Codable`).